# How to edit or input in focus InputElement with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with input from my own numpad made by javascript. I have double input must be fill. I want to input in InputElement when focused only. When I click the button in my own numpad, but the results are inputted in the two inputs that I have. So, how to make my input just to InputElement has focused ?

i have try using `if($('input').in(':focus'))` but give no response

here the input

```
<div class='form-row align-items-center'>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
         <div class='input-group-text'>Rp.</div>
      </div>
      <input id='paymentnominal' name='nominal' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Nominal'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
        <div class='input-group-text'>123</div>
      </div>
    <input id='cardnumber' name='cardnumber' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Card Number'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <button id='submit' class='btn bg-maroon mb-2'>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here the my own numpad

```
<button class='numpad1'>1</button>
<button class='numpad2'>2</button>
<button class='numpad3'>3</button>
<button class='numpad4'>4</button>
<button class='numpad5'>5</button>
<button class='numpad6'>6</button>
<button class='numpad7'>7</button>
<button class='numpad8'>8</button>
<button class='numpad9'>9</button>
<button class='numpad0'>0</button>
<button class='numpad00'>00</button>
<button class='numpadx'>X</button>
```

and this javascript function I have tried

```
$('.numpad1').click(function(){
  $( 'input' ).val( function( index, val ) {
    return val + "1";
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @halococ, You can refer this: https://codepen.io/hasanbilgehan/pen/KpjrML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've clicked on a `<button>`, *neither* input has focus anymore. You need to keep track of the last-focused input.

```js
var focusedInput = null;

$(document.body).on('focus', 'input', function() {
  focusedInput = this;
});

$('.numpad1').click(function() {
  if (focusedInput) {
    focusedInput.value = focusedInput.value + '1';
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='form-row align-items-center'>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
         <div class='input-group-text'>Rp.</div>
      </div>
      <input id='paymentnominal' name='nominal' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Nominal'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
        <div class='input-group-text'>123</div>
      </div>
    <input id='cardnumber' name='cardnumber' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Card Number'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <button id='submit' class='btn bg-maroon mb-2'>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class='numpad1'>1</button>
  <button class='numpad2'>2</button>
  <button class='numpad3'>3</button>
  <button class='numpad4'>4</button>
  <button class='numpad5'>5</button>
  <button class='numpad6'>6</button>
  <button class='numpad7'>7</button>
  <button class='numpad8'>8</button>
  <button class='numpad9'>9</button>
  <button class='numpad0'>0</button>
  <button class='numpad00'>00</button>
  <button class='numpadx'>X</button>
</div>
```

More generally:

```js
var focusedInput = null;

$(document.body).on('focus', 'input', function() {
  focusedInput = this;
});

$('button.numpad').click(function() {
  if (focusedInput) {
    focusedInput.value = focusedInput.value + this.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='form-row align-items-center'>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
         <div class='input-group-text'>Rp.</div>
      </div>
      <input id='paymentnominal' name='nominal' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Nominal'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <div class='input-group mb-2'>
      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
        <div class='input-group-text'>123</div>
      </div>
    <input id='cardnumber' name='cardnumber' value='' class='form-control' placeholder='Card Number'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-auto'>
    <button id='submit' class='btn bg-maroon mb-2'>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <button class='numpad'>1</button>
  <button class='numpad'>2</button>
  <button class='numpad'>3</button>
  <button class='numpad'>4</button>
  <button class='numpad'>5</button>
  <button class='numpad'>6</button>
  <button class='numpad'>7</button>
  <button class='numpad'>8</button>
  <button class='numpad'>9</button>
  <button class='numpad'>0</button>
  <button class='numpad'>00</button>
  <button class='numpadx'>X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this code not running in my javascript : ```$('input').focus(function() {
  focusedInput = this;
});``` .  when i using 
```var focusedInput = null;

$('body').on( "input" ).focus(function() {
  focusedInput = this;
}); ```not running too. Look at my editing. Complete html in input

Comment: `on('input')` is an event, not a reference to `input` elements, so that certainly wouldn't work. I haven't seen an edit that demonstrates the problem you describe in the first part.

Comment: I updated the answer to demonstrate the correct usage of `on()` in this context.

Comment: thanks. ```$(document.body).on('focus', 'input', function() {
  focusedInput = this;
});``` work. One part again if i click button. Still find error.

Comment: thanks. All work fine, i has edited your answer with my script code

Answer (score 1):

```
var numPad1 = document.getElementsByClassName('numpad1')[0];
var paymentInput = document.getElementById('paymentnominal');
numPad1.onclick= function(){
   paymentInput.value = paymentInput.value+''+1;
}
```

Comment: i want to input when my mouse focus in InputElement without id. can it ?

Comment: You can do something like this ...
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
inputs[i].onmouseover = function(){
inputs[i].focus();
}